# SQL Casting Groups of Columns Together Efficiently

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I have a series of T-SQL queries that I use that are running very slowly.  One part of the query that I suspect is causing some problems is a series of Casts that I have to do on them.

This is the problem.  I have to combine the 4 columns together as a nvarchar/varchar as the combination of them form a (semi)-unique key for an entry in another table (horrible idea I know, but I'm stuck with it).

The four columns are:
t_orno, t_reno, t_pono, t_srnb: all INT columns without indexes.

The way I have been doing this is like so:

```
Cast(t_orno AS nvarchar(10)) + '-' + Cast(t_reno as nvarchar(10)) + 
    '-' + Cast(t_pono as nvarchar(5)) + '-' + Cast(t_srnb as nvarchar(5))
```

Unfortunately I'm stuck with having to merge these columns together.  Is there a better way of doing this?  The queries need to be more efficient and there has got to be a better way than casting all four individually?

Assume: that the database is completely unchangeable -- which sadly it is... (don't want to get into that..)

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:  As per a request for more info on the tables:

Both tables that are being queried from only contain one index, and it is on the PK column.  Again note, that nothing can be added/changed on these tables.

The table being joined contains the combination of those four columns: 
BaanID > nvarchar, no index.

Comment: Can you include the data structures (including indexes) of the tables in question and the query you are using to join them?

Comment: @MarkBannister Well there are about 5 different queries that I'm working to improve that contain fairly complex CTE's.  It would be very difficult to provide them and explain what is going on -- this is why I focused on just this aspect of the query. I will try to add more info though.

Comment: @MarkBannister Not sure what other relevant information to include.  Let me know if there is anything else you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the reverse, i.e. splitting "an entry in another table" on the "-" character and casting each to int - may yield better performance?

Comment: Interesting.  I like your thinking @BarryKaye.  Could you give a basic example of split and/or some useful links.

Comment: @ImGreg: Depending on the complexity of the format of the entries, you might do with just a series of [`SUBSTRING()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx "SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)") calls with fixed arguments to cut out the integer parts, or you might have to additionally use the [`CHARINDEX()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx "CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)") to find the right positions of the numeric components within the entries. (You would likely be searching for `'-'`s within the string and calculate the lengths of the substrings between them).

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use a persisted view and create an index on it. Here is an article that may help you: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx.

Or you could add a computed column to the table containing the t_* columns and index this column.

Comment: Are these indexed views practical for very large databases @Dan?  The table that contains these key 4 columns is about 4Million rows and expands about 50k a day.

Comment: We've had similar figures for a project and SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard handled the queries nicely. If I were you, I'd use a backup of your database to create a test environment and check the performance of insert/update/delete/select operations.

Comment: Excellent.  I have been working to improve them, but the poor setup of the database has made it challenging.  Haven't learned enough about performance of queries yet. *Work in progress*

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by computed column?

Comment: Here is the MSDN reference, it will give you all the needed information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the crucial point:

> The table being joined contains the combination of those four columns: BaanID > nvarchar, no index

Unless you are dealing with relatively small tables, joining two tables together on columns that are not indexed is likely to be costly.